# How can I block Babel to change this to undefined?

Tags: javascript, configuration, babeljs

I have UMD ES2015 module

```
(function (global, factory) {
    (typeof exports === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(exports)) === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) : typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) : factory(global.XmlDSigJs = global.XmlDSigJs || {});
})(this, function (exports) {
// My code here
...
```

After Babel compilation I've got `(undefined, function (exports)`.

Is there any bable options to bock this changing?

Comment: How are you using Babel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is already written as a UMD module, and thus does not use `import` or `export`, then you can do

```
"presets": [
  ['es2015', {modules: false}]
],
```

Pass `modules: false` to your configured preset will tell Babel not to consider the file an "ES6 Module", which is what is triggering the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You've said this is an "ES2015 module." `this` at the top-level scope of an ES2015 module **is** `undefined`. If your code expects it to be something else, that code is incorrect.

Normally, you don't refer to the global object or create globals in modules at all; that's part of the reason we have modules, to avoid global pollution.

In those rare cases where you need to, the way you do that varies depending on the environment. In browsers, you can use `window`, which is a global variable that refers to the window object, which is the JavaScript global object in browsers. In NodeJS, you can use `global`, which is a global variable referring to the JavaScript global object.

But again, creating globals in a module is an anti-pattern. A module should export what it provides, not make it global.

Comment: It's not my own UMD implementation. Here is an example for [config](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/xml-core/blob/master/rollup.config.js) file I used. It has correct result for me (`this`). But if run `npm run build:web` for [xmldsigjs](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/xmldsigjs) you'll get `undefined` (cannot run in browser). I don't use the same `rollup.config` for `xmldsig`, cause [issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/issues/125)